# Error running Vagrant on Ubuntu 12.04 on EC2

Tags: vagrant

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS installed on Amazon EC2, architectue x86_64 with m1.medium machine type.

To install virtualbox  I did

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Now,

```
vagrant init precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
vagrant up
```

always halts saying

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Box 'precise32' was not found. Fetching box from specified URL for
the provider 'virtualbox'. Note that if the URL does not have
a box for this provider, you should interrupt Vagrant now and add
the box yourself. Otherwise Vagrant will attempt to download the
full box prior to discovering this error.
Downloading or copying the box...
Extracting box...te: 8240k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
Successfully added box 'precise32' with provider 'virtualbox'!
[default] Importing base box 'precise32'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
```

Answer (score 3):

I also see the same result ("Booting VM" forever). Looks like this is not an option for vagrant: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1631

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an error. It pulls down the box from the URL you gave, imports it, and starts to boot. Once it finishes booting, you should be able to `vagrant ssh` into the VM.

Comment: But it never finishes booting. It just halts at "Booting VM..."

Comment: Have you checked the status in virtualbox? You should be able to see the boot progress.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then vagrant is stuck at "Booting VM" and never actually starts?

Try setting an environment variable to enable logging

```
$ VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG vagrant up
```

http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/debugging.html

Also, try using a different image. The precise32 image might have an older version of virtual box guest additions.